# Issue: Writing more data than expected in debian packages

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, package, debian

I have detected a problem today when building docker images. I am trying to install the following libraries:

```
apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install build-essential msodbcsql17 mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
```

And I have this issue:

```
Err:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod stretch/main amd64 Packages 
 Writing more data than expected (93446 > 93230) 
 Hashes of expected file: 
 - Filesize:93230 [weak] 
 - SHA512:6d9952cd289566e58aad057b0c24d1d450c2dc8adfd3871b06f843c6a8ea84853f6cda10e390ffddc9621299d2dcfe516e488a6fea215928d5446a52754dfa9a 
 - SHA256:c5c7ad271c940d9533231e61043d923d93f5bde7ab9927d8da9be3964c440bd4 
 - SHA1:46696f97ceccbacdcdd9dda6d68fdbc1f7b76cd0 [weak] 
 - MD5Sum:49e53481a1cbdac343dd7d54cc3c2c52 [weak] 
 Release file created at: Wed, 17 Jun 2020 00:12:39 +0000 
Fetched 4009 B in 0s (8166 B/s) 
Reading package lists... 
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2 Writing more data than expected (93446 > 93230) 
 Hashes of expected file: 
 - Filesize:93230 [weak] 
 - SHA512:6d9952cd289566e58aad057b0c24d1d450c2dc8adfd3871b06f843c6a8ea84853f6cda10e390ffddc9621299d2dcfe516e488a6fea215928d5446a52754dfa9a 
 - SHA256:c5c7ad271c940d9533231e61043d923d93f5bde7ab9927d8da9be3964c440bd4 
 - SHA1:46696f97ceccbacdcdd9dda6d68fdbc1f7b76cd0 [weak] 
 - MD5Sum:49e53481a1cbdac343dd7d54cc3c2c52 [weak]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was related to package servers. I have tried again and it works.